# Trading View Strategy show long orders signals on bars which was not defined for long orders

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

i am working on a Trading View Strategy which using a Squeeze Momentum as Source.

I don't understand why a long or short order is set on bars which are not defined for long orders, like putting long order at the top of a bullish trend shortly before the trend change, or short orders nearly at the bottom of a bearish trend like shown in the screenshot

[image]

where others next to it are within the Definition.

I am pretty new to PineScript and never coding before.

Yellow Dot in Screenshot is for Squeeze On, Green for Squeeze Off, as visible the Short Order for example was set in the Bottom and when a Squeeze was On, even the Signal was set to Squeeze Off.

The Strategy is:

```
//@version=5
strategy(title='Squeeze Momentum strategy PSv5',  overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100, calc_on_every_tick = true)

import TradingView/Strategy/3
import TradingView/ta/5

length = input(20, title='BB Length')
mult = input(2.0, title='BB MultFactor')
source = close
lengthKC = input(20, title='KC Length')
multKC = input(1.5, title='KC MultFactor')
useTrueRange = input(true, title='Use TrueRange (KC)')

// Defining MA
ma = ta.sma(source, length)

// Calculate BB
basis = ma
dev = mult * ta.stdev(source, length)
upperBB = basis + dev
lowerBB = basis - dev

// Calculate KC
range_1 = useTrueRange ? ta.tr : high - low
rangema = ta.sma(range_1, lengthKC)
upperKC = ma + rangema * multKC
lowerKC = ma - rangema * multKC

// SqzON | SqzOFF | noSqz
sqzOn = lowerBB > lowerKC and upperBB < upperKC
sqzOff = lowerBB < lowerKC and upperBB > upperKC
noSqz = sqzOn == false and sqzOff == false

// Momentum
val = ta.linreg(source - math.avg(math.avg(ta.highest(high, lengthKC), ta.lowest(low, lengthKC)), ta.sma(close, lengthKC)), lengthKC, 0)

// Plots
iff_1 = val > nz(val[1]) ? #00FF00 : #008000
iff_2 = val < nz(val[1]) ? #FF0000 : #800000
bcolor = val > 0 ? iff_1 : iff_2
scolor = noSqz ? color.blue : sqzOn ? color.yellow : color.green

plot(val, color=bcolor, style=plot.style_histogram,linewidth=4, transp=50)
plot(0, color=scolor, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=4)

sqzGREY = ta.crossunder(lowerBB, lowerKC) and ta.crossover(upperBB, upperKC)
plotshape(sqzGREY, style=shape.circle, location=location.bottom, size=size.tiny)

// Configure Signals

long = sqzOn and val < (val[1]) ? 1:0

if long //and barstate.isconfirmed
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, alert_message = 'Open Long')
  
short = sqzOff and val > nz(val[7])? 1:0

if short //and barstate.isconfirmed
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, alert_message = 'Open Short')
```

When i set that the signal for long and short, should open in the opposite trends, then they should not open in their own trend, at the Top for Long or at the Bottom for Short.

Answer (score 0):

Look:

```
short = sqzOff and val > nz(val[7])? 1:0
```

val[**seven**]

try this:

```
short = sqzOff and val > nz(val[1])? 1:0
```